# Read xml lines of a file and copy to an array in Perl?

Tags: xml, perl

I have a file named test.xml that is like this:

```
<temp id="abc1">32769</temp><temp id="abc2">0</temp><temp id="abc3">N</temp><temp id="abc4">1</temp>
<test id="abc5">D</test><test id="abc6">NS</test><test id="abc7">NG</test>
```

I want to introduce newline character after `</temp>,</test>` and then copy each line to an array(say @array) like this:

```
$array[1]=<temp id="abc1">32769</temp>
$array[2]=<temp id="abc2">0</temp>
$array[3]=<temp id="abc3">N</temp>
$array[4]=<temp id="abc4">1</temp>
$array[5]=<test id="abc5">D</test>
$array[6]=<test id="abc6">NS</test>
$array[7]=<test id="abc7">NG</test>
```

i have tried by using foreach loop

```
open (INPUT, "$test file"); 
foreach (<INPUT>) { 
   s/\<\/test\>/\<\/test\>\n/g;
   s/\<\/temp\>/\<\/temp\>\n/g; 
} 
my array = <INPUT>;
```

Comment: Why do you need it? XML is easier to handle with special modules like [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML) or [XML::Twig](http://p3rl.org/XML::Twig).

Comment: @user3723454 Add it to your question using the edit funcction not as commant

Comment: @jens added to my question, m just a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you try the following?

```
open(DATA, "<pqr.xml") or die "Couldn't open file pqr.xml, $!";
my $y='';
while(<DATA>){
    $_=~s/(<\/temp>)/$1\n/g;
    $_=~s/(<\/test>)/$1\n/g;
    $_=~s/(\n)+/\n/g;
    print $_;
    $y.=$_;
}
my @x=split(/\n/,$y);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex to get your data i.e lazily match your data until `/` and then again lazily match until `>`.:

Put the result into `@array`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string='<temp id="abc1">32769</temp><temp id="abc2">0</temp><temp id="abc3">N</temp><temp id="abc4">1</temp>
<test id="abc5">D</test><test id="abc6">NS</test><test id="abc7">NG</test>';

my @array=$string=~/(<.+?(?=[\/]).+?(?=[>])>)/g;

print Dumper(\@array);
```

**Output:**

```
[
  '<temp id="abc1">32769</temp>',
  '<temp id="abc2">0</temp>',
  '<temp id="abc3">N</temp>',
  '<temp id="abc4">1</temp>',
  '<test id="abc5">D</test>',
  '<test id="abc6">NS</test>',
  '<test id="abc7">NG</test>'
 ];
```

Answer (score 1):

XML is a bad idea to parse with regular expressions. A really bad idea, because it'll sort of work in the short term but one day will break messily and no one will really know why.

Please don't do this - your future sysadmins and maintenance programmers will be sad.

Please please please use an XML parser. Several exist. (Just not `XML::Simple`, which lies about being simple).

But I would also question why you need to have your elements like that in an array at all? What are you using that information for? IF it's to reconstruct some XML... don't. Just use the parser instead.

Otherwise:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new( 'pretty_print' => 'indented_a' );
$twig->parse( \*DATA );

#print reformatted XML
$twig->print;

my @things;

#extract elements
foreach my $element ( $twig->root->children ) {

    #insert into array.
    push( @things, $element->sprint );
}

print Dumper \@things;

__DATA__
<root>
<temp id="abc1">32769</temp><temp id="abc2">0</temp><temp id="abc3">N</temp><temp id="abc4">1</temp>
<test id="abc5">D</test><test id="abc6">NS</test><test id="abc7">NG</test>
</root>
```

However, you could do some other more useful things, data structure wise. Like convert to a hash, which is probably more useful

e.g.:

```
my %stuff;

#extract elements
foreach my $element ( $twig->root->children ) {
   my $tag = $element -> tag;
   my $id = $element -> att('id'); 
   $stuff{$tag}{$id} = $element -> trimmed_text; 
}

print Dumper \%stuff;
```

Creates a data structure looking like:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'test' => {
                    'abc5' => 'D',
                    'abc6' => 'NS',
                    'abc7' => 'NG'
                  },
          'temp' => {
                    'abc1' => '32769',
                    'abc4' => '1',
                    'abc2' => '0',
                    'abc3' => 'N'
                  }
        };
```

As to the reason why using regex for XML parsing is bad? Each of these are semantically identical XML. Regular expressions to handle it become extremely complex and painful, because you need to handle tag nesting and encapsulation.

```
<root>
<temp id="abc1">32769</temp><temp id="abc2">0</temp><temp id="abc3">N</temp><temp id="abc4">1</temp>
<test id="abc5">D</test><test id="abc6">NS</test><test id="abc7">NG</test>
</root>

<root>
  <temp id="abc1">32769</temp>
  <temp id="abc2">0</temp>
  <temp id="abc3">N</temp>
  <temp id="abc4">1</temp>
  <test id="abc5">D</test>
  <test id="abc6">NS</test>
  <test id="abc7">NG</test>
</root>

<root
><temp
id="abc1"
>32769</temp><temp
id="abc2"
>0</temp><temp
id="abc3"
>N</temp><temp
id="abc4"
>1</temp><test
id="abc5"
>D</test><test
id="abc6"
>NS</test><test
id="abc7"
>NG</test></root>

<root><temp id="abc1">32769</temp><temp id="abc2">0</temp><temp id="abc3">N</temp><temp id="abc4">1</temp><test id="abc5">D</test><test id="abc6">NS</test><test id="abc7">NG</test></root>
```